# How to change color on mousehover of td of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to use JQuery. On mouse hover event I wanna change the color of background of TDs. 
This is what I have tried so far. But not working at all.

```
<html>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$('.row1td1').hover(function() {
    $('.row2td1').css('color', 'red');
}, function() {
    $('.row2td1').css('color', '');
});
</script>
<head>
        <!-- Bring to you by http://www.CSSTableGenerator.com -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" type="text/css"/>   
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="CSS_Table_Example" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
            <table >
                <tr> 
                    <td id="row1td0">
                        Title 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="row1td1">
                        Title 2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Title 3
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td id="row2td0">
                        Title 1
                    </td>
                    <td id="row2td1">
                        Title 2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Title 3
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change color of what? font,background, border?

Comment: Why would you need javascript for that ?

Comment: @raam86 From the example, it is the color of the text.

Comment: The issue is the missing document ready handler .

Comment: Sorry background color

Comment: And of course, those are ID's not classes ?

Comment: no.. Not classes.. just ID

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using jQuery for that, but the problem is that you use `id="row2td1"`, and then try to access it as a class.

Try this CSS:

```css
#row2td1:hover {color:red}
```

Comment: Just because jQuery exists, doesn't mean you need to use it for everything! CSS or vanilla js solution wins every time.

Comment: @kolink. On #row1td1:hover i need to change color of #row2td1

Comment: +1, Every one forget the main goal, just start solution on existing code, instead of thinking about another easy way to improve.

Comment: @NickR I agree with you, but in this case, you need javascript (helped with jquery to be easier) since when you hover one, it change another one who's not a sibling nor a children.

Comment: Why not use jquery? If you've already loaded it in for animations on your site you might as well use it for the benefit of other developers so that they can read the code more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not waiting till the DOM is ready, try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('#row1td1').hover(
        function() {
            $('#row2td1').css('color', 'red');
        }, 
        function() {
            $('#row2td1').css('color', '');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: What if I need to use class. So instead of #row2td1 if i use .red class? I tried this $(.red1').css('color', 'red'); but didn't work

Comment: @user1327064 well, without the HTML, i can't tell you why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

As the other two said, you need to make sure you are tagging by ID and not by class, as well as making sure that the document is ready before doing any jQuery (which I personally believe to be the best for this situation).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(#row1td1).hover(function() {
        $(#row2td1).css('color', 'red');
    }, function() {
        $(#row2td1).css('color', '');
    });
});
```

Comment: What if I need to use class. So instead of  #row2td1 if i use .red class? I tried this $(.red1').css('color', 'red'); but didn't work

Comment: You don't have a 'red' or 'red1' class? If you want to use $(.red).SOMETHING then your HTML tag would need to have a "class='red'"

Comment: Make sure there aren't quotes around .red

Comment: Although the css color attribute will change text color. You need to be using background-color

Answer (score 0):

As I addressed in your question you said you want to change color or background color of **TDs** so I am gonna give you another solution which is derived from **Kolink** may be use full to you.

**HTML**

```
<table >
    <tr> 
        <td class="row" id="row1td0">
            Title 2
        </td>
        <td class="row" id="row1td1">
            Title 2
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            Title 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td class="row" id="row2td0">
            Title 1
        </td>
        <td class="row" id="row2td1">
            Title 2
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            Title 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and add css to your code

```
    .row:hover {color:red}
```

Hope it will be use full for you...

Comment: That will not work, OP want to change an element when an other element is being hovered.